# Fill in missing column1 values for all distinct column2 values present in the dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table t looks like below:

```
+-----+------+-------+
| key | week | value |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |    1 |    10 |
|   1 |    2 |    20 |
|   2 |    1 |   100 |
|   2 |    2 |   200 |
|   2 |    3 |   300 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

`key` 2 has `value` present for `week` 1, 2, and 3,
but `key` 1 has only `value` for `week` 1 and 2

How do I write a query for adding a row for `key` 1 and a missing `week` 3 with a default `value` of 0, so that the result table looks like below:

```
+-----+------+-------+
| key | week | value |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |    1 |    10 |
|   1 |    2 |    20 |
|   1 |    3 |     0 |
|   2 |    1 |   100 |
|   2 |    2 |   200 |
|   2 |    3 |   300 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I tried both cross joins and full outer joins (on a distinct list of weeks) but somehow did not manage to arrive at a desired solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select k.key, w.week, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct key from t) k cross join
     (select distinct week from t) w left join
     t
     on t.key = k.key and t.week = w.week
order by k.key, w.week;
```

This uses the original table as the source for keys and weeks.  If you have other tables with this information you can use that.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!!! Could you please update the query above with the corrected alieases, so that it does not confuse others? (it currently throws an error) select 
 k.k, 
 w.w, 
 coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct key k from t) k 
 cross join (select distinct week w from t) w 
left join 
 t on t.key = k.k and t.week = w.w
order by 
 k.k, w.w;

Comment: @Dennis . . . I removed the single character column aliases.  Those were typos.